# To display the lowest price

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

here I have a sheet which have to give two results. one result is working fine but I stuck in finding the next one. in the sheet below I receive products from two suppliers, I want to see which are the new products given by 'second supplier'. And that is working fine. you can see the result in the 'Output tab'(one of you from this platform helped me for that). but my current issue is 90% of the products which supplied from both is same. if the products which 'second supplier' gives matches the products got from 'first supplier' it wont display in Output. but if 'second supplier' gives the lowest price than 'first supplier' then we can't miss that product, it must appear in the 'Output tab' along with the new products. the eg of how the output must be is there in the 'Est Output' tab

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19qDWicrqoNiltT1VJE6GdOMTHmjL-GT5YOmHJEh46hc/edit#gid=502304505

any type of help would be appreciable.

Note : if it is not possible then pls display the products with lowest price in the another tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in A2:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF('Second Supplier'!B2:B<IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Second Supplier'!A2:A,'First Supplier'!A2:B,2,FALSE),9^9),'Second Supplier'!A2:B,),"Select * WHERE Col2 >0",0))`

Here, the formula checks the price of 'Second Supplier' against the price of 'First Supplier'. If it is less, the 'Second Supplier' item and price are returned. If it returns an error, it means that the 'Second Supplier' item was not found in the 'First Supplier' list; in this case, `IFERROR` still returns the 'Second Supplier' item and price (because it means it is unique). If neither of these is true, then null is returned (which is accomplished by the comma with nothing after it).

`TRIM` makes sure you don't have any entries of stray spaces (which you currently do have).

Finally, `QUERY` trims the list of any null entries.

**ADDENDUM** (based on additional comments)

To show only entries where second supplier's product is new or differs from first supplier's price by more than 2%:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF('Second Supplier'!B2:B<=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Second Supplier'!A2:A,'First Supplier'!A2:B,2,FALSE)*97%,9^9),'Second Supplier'!A2:B,),"Select * WHERE Col2 > 0",0))`

**ADDENDUM 2** (based on more additional comments)

This will compare Supplier 2 to the most recent Supplier 1 data by using `SORT` to sort Supplier 1 data in reverse order by `ROW`.

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(IF('Second Supplier'!B2:B<=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Second Supplier'!A2:A,SORT('First Supplier'!A2:B,ROW('First Supplier'!A2:A),0),2,FALSE)*98%,9^9),'Second Supplier'!A2:B,),"Select * WHERE Col2 > 0",0))`

Comment: @Erick.. thanks a lot. the output is great

Comment: @Erick can u please help me with an update , that now it is displaying the lowest price but can we display the price only which is greater than 2% ? eg if previous week price is 50 and current week price is 49.99 (bcz 0.1 is not a big difference right ? ), then it is not necessary to display that. display only when current week price is 49. ie 2% of 50 is 49.

Comment: @Erick a sample of how output must be is there in the sheet. so that you may get the clear idea what i was trying to explain. please compare Erick help and out put must be so that u can see the products with the price less than 2% is only displayed in out put must be tab.

Comment: See the new formula added to my post above. I have also made this update in your sample sheet, "Erik Help."

Comment: great ,, but can u use TRIM here because there is spaces in between

Comment: @Erick when I changed 2% to 3% output leaves an empty row, how can we remove empty lines ?

Comment: TRIM is not necessary. See update to second formula (also in your sheet).

Comment: @Erick.. my friend you really helped me in this task.. I really really appreciate you. as u helped in generating this can u do one and last update for me? is it possible to match the name in the second supplier with latest name in in first supplier? ie if perfume comes twice in first supplier , and if the perfume in second supplier , it have to match with the second arrived perfume. if you go to the sheet you will get what I meant.

Comment: See my further updated post. I also made this formula change on your sheet.

Comment: @Erick am really thank full for your patience and helping mentality.. thanks a lot.. god bless

Comment: @Erick can you come to that sheet again please When I re arranged the cells according to my original sheet.. some error occurred. please take a look